# Is there an “elif” equivalent in for/else statements

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

In if/elif/else statements, `elif`s are checked if the `if` is false, and if both the `if` and `elif`s are false then the `else` is run.

For loops have something similar with the `else` keyword - if the loop doesn’t encounter a break, then the code inside `else` is run.

So, for loops have an `else` equivalent to if/elif/else statements. My question is however, is there an equivalent to `elif`.

I’m thinking that it would be something along the lines of:

- Run for loop. If no `break` is encountered, go onto the next
  specified loop
- Run the specified for loop, if no `break` is encountered, go onto the
  next.
- Repeat until no more loops are left, and if no `break`s have been
  encountered up to this point, run the `else`.

I’m aware you can emulate this effect. Just as you can do this with if/else statements to emulate the `elif`:

```
if condition:
    do_something()
else:
    if another_condition:
        do_something_else()
    else:
        default()
```

you can do this with for loops:

```
for x in y:
    if condition:
        break
else:
    for n in m:
        if another_condition:
            break
    else:
        default()
```

While the above code is valid, like with if/else statements, it’s faily ugly and I was hoping to find a better alternative.

Comment: There just isn't anywhere near as much of a use case for an "elfor" as there is for elif or for-else. I don't think I've seen a single piece of code where "elfor" even would have been *applicable*, let alone useful.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica you're probably right, but I think it's still a fair question to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If you look at the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) of the `for` statement:

```
for_stmt:
    | 'for' star_targets 'in' ~ star_expressions ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] block [else_block] 
    . . .
```

It ends in an optional `else_block`, but nothing else. Your emulation is as good as you'll get I believe.

Answer (score 1):

While the for-loop syntax doesn't allow this (as shown by @Carcigenicate), you can keep nesting levels down by using a `try-else`:

```
try:
    for x in y:
        if z:
            raise SomeException
    for m in n:
        if o:
            raise SomeException
except SomeException:
    pass
else:
    default()
```

A cleaner way, however, might wrap the loops in functions:

```
# these can be more complex non-anonymous functions
f1 = lambda: any(1 for x in y if z)
f2 = lambda: any(1 for m in n if o)
f3 = ...

if not any(f() for f in (f1, f2, f3)):
    default()
```

Comment: Would this be recommended over a nested for/else?

Comment: The [Python Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says *"Flat is better than nested"* =) however, using an Exception to manipulate control flow might border on abuse. I would probably wrap each loop in a function, return `True` from the if-block, and execute `default` like: `if not any(fnc() for fnc in fncs): default()` where `fncs` is an iterable over the different functions.

Answer (score 1):

What if you make the variable that determins whether you should continue global? Since if any of the conditions are met, you don't want to continue with any of the following loops this should work:

```
def do_something():
    for i in range(3):
        condition = i < 3
        if not condition:
            return False

    return True


def do_something_else():
    for i in range(3):
        condition = i < 2
        if not condition:
            return False

    return True


condition_met = True
if condition_met:
    print('we start here')
    condition_met = do_something()
if condition_met:
    print('and should get here')
    condition_met = do_something_else()
if condition_met:
    print('but not here')
```

It may not be amazing, but at least it's not nested, and sort of looks like the syntax you're looking for.

You could also use a while loop:

```
operations = [do_something, do_something_else] 
i = 0
while condition_met and i < len(operations):
    condition_met = operations[i]()
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure, but maybe while will be ok for you

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
  if condition:
    break
  i += 1
```

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question :/